# do i need to use imagedestroy() in this loop?

Tags: php, image, gd

I'm using the same variable to create a lot of images, so each one overrides the previous one. Do I need to use `imagedestroy()`?

ex:

```
<?php

foreach($paths as $path) {

    $image = imagecreatefrompng($path);
    //more code...
    imagedestroy($image); //--------> should i do this?
}
imagedestroy($image); //---------> or should i do this?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you are doing *exactly* you should put `imagedestroy()` within the loop to free the memory and make space for the next images. On the other hand it just doesn't hurt

Comment: but, my doubt is, when i override the variable, am i destroying that image? or should i mannually destroy it?

Comment: In doubt destroy it manually. When you unset a variable PHP free the associated resources as soon as the garbage collector runs, but I wouldn't assume, that this will free the memory allocated by the GD-library/-extension immediately too (as long as I don't know the internal details of that extension). Else you may run into a memory leak, because without a reference (the variable) you cannot destroy the image yourself anymore.